# Как получить из словаря ключи, значения которых совпадают, средствами linq

Tags: c#, linq, словари

Мне нужно вернуть Ключи словаря, с одинаковыми values, средствами linq.

Я понимаю принцип работы написанного запроса так:
Из списка ключей -> взять список значений таких ключей из словаря -> добавить в коллекцию те ключи, значения которых удовлетворяют условию. В чем ошибка?

```
    private Dictionary<string, string> clientsBase = new()
    {
        { "al1992@gmail.com", "Алексей И.Г."},
        { "crusher777@gmail.com", "Петрова М.Р"},
        { "yayaN25@gmail.com", "Иванов А.А" },
        { "elena.k.@gmail.com", "Иванов А.А" }

    };

    public string GetClientEmail(string name)
    {
        var fltEmails = clientsBase.Keys.Select(v => clientsBase[v])
                                        .Where(n => n.Equals(name));

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var fltEmail in fltEmails) builder.Append(fltEmail);

        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: `clientsBase.GroupBy(x => x.Value);`

Comment: Это ведь просто вернет элементы с уникальными values, нет?

Comment: Можно вообще использовать структуру даннх типа `Dictionary<string, string[]>`, где ключом будет имя, а значением будет массив емейлов, тогда задача сведется к однострочнику безо всяких Linq запросов. Но вообще решение странное, ведь может быть несколько разных людей с одинаковыми фамилиями и инициалами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
public string GetClientEmail(string name)
{
    var fltEmails = clientsBase
        .Where(v => v.Value == name)
        .Select(v => v.Key);

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var fltEmail in fltEmails) builder.Append(fltEmail);

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

В варианте из вопроса проблема в том, что сначала выбираются ключи, потом по ключам выбираются имена и уже эти имена фильтруются. А доступа к ключам на этом этапе уже нет.

Comment: `return string.Join(",", fltEmails);`

Comment: `.ToList()` здесь лишний, без него оптимальнее получится.

Comment: Да, согласен, так гораздо короче. Навряд ли есть варианты имен, для которых будет так много совпадений, чтобы это повлияло на производительность и понадобился StringBuilder. Суммируя, можно вообще в одну строку записать: return string.Join(",", clientsBase.Where(v => v.Value == name).Select(v => v.Key));

Comment: Насчет .ToList() не понял, можно какую-нибудь ссылку на почитать? Без него запрос выполняется в момент обращения, с ним сразу, почему может влиять на производительность? Или оптимальнее - в смысле лаконичнее?

Comment: Во втором случае не создается список, а значения из перечисления используются напрямую. Со списком вы сначала перечисляете запрос, а потом сам список, то есть 2 прохода получится.

Comment: @alexsteeel это вы так думаете что не будет так много совпадений, а как дело дойдет до реальной бд где будет сотни никнеймов "asdf asdf" то...

Comment: @Aarnihauta да даже если дело не дойдет до БД, надо сразу учиться не писать лишнее.

Comment: @Aarnihauta ну тут уже обсуждение выходит за рамки изначального вопроса =) Если мы переходим к рассмотрению БД с неуникальными никнеймами, то условия меняются. В целом я согласен, что условия могут быть разные, поэтому изначальный StringBuilder и не менял. И все-таки вопрос не в обработке конкретного сценария с именами, а в выборке ключей по значению.

Comment: @aepot понял о чем речь, спасибо. Просто никогда не сталкивался с проблемами в этом плане. Если объем данных настолько велик, что создание List влияет на производительность, то это уже скорее проблема не с ToList, а с самой выборкой. В данном случае действительно лишняя операция.

Comment: Использование ToList иногда сильно помогает при отладке. Без него дебаггер может скакать по выражениям чёрт знает как.

Comment: @alexsteeel да без разницы, какой объем. Бесполезное создание прокси-объектов - это лишний мусор в памяти. Чем больше мусора, тем больше у GC работы, а чем больше у GC работы, тем жирнее он будет выставлять паузы в выполении вашего кода для уборки. Это тенденция общей произовдительности приложения. Здесь вы создали сотню лишних объектов, в другом месте у вас начало "икать" медиа в приложении. Казалось бы, совершенно несвязанные друг с другом вещи. Культура написания кода с контролем аллокаций объектов пока еще никому не навредила. Всё хорошо в меру, само собой.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov в подавляющем большинстве случаев дебаггер Results View показывает из перечисления нормально, но вы правы в какой-то степени, да.

Answer (score 3):

Можно например так, но конечно способ @alexsteeel выглядит интуитивно понятнее

```
public string GetEmailsByName(Dictionary<string, string> items, string name)
{
    var emails = items.GroupBy(x => x.Value == name)
                      .First(x => x.Key)
                      .Select(x => x.Key);

    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var item in emails)
        sb.Append(item);

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Здесь есть один минус по сравнению с принятым ответом, если имени нет в выборке, будет исключение.

Comment: @aepot да, знаю, я так специально написал чтоб свои руки не сували куда попало